# One RAM module doesn't Work iMac

Tags: memory

I have a 2009 iMac. I had to install more RAM of 2 x 4 GB (replacing 2 x 2 GB.). One of the new slots doesn't work. I shut down and switched the two sides. Now the other slot doesn't work. I need this solved by today.

Comment: So, if the other slot doesn't work when you swap them… that would point to one of the RAM sticks having failed. Double-check, one stick - test in each slot, then the other stick likewise.

Comment: You will have to accept the likelihood of diagnosing this issue by today is very slim.  It sounds like you purchased incompatible memory.  Verify the original memory still works

Comment: @Ramhound - that iMac has only two slots, so the new sticks are all there is to test - one apparently works, the other doesn't… though the diagnostic employed doesn't seem too strict as yet ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - The original modules are 2 2 GB modules.

Comment: Clean out the slots.  Blow them out.  Look carefully at the pins/contacts.

Answer (score 0):

By process of elimination…

Test each RAM stick [all 4 of them] in each of the two available slots, one at a time [that's 8 tests, in total.]

If, as I suspect, the older 2GB sticks work in both slots & one of the new stick works in both slots… yet the other new stick doesn't work in either slot…
The stick is dead & needs replacing.